# How to remove array keys while exporting using Mattwebsite excel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I am exporting data to excel using Maatwebsite excel. I am using laravel framework. My array is looking like this:-

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Salary
        [2] => Age
        [3] => Gender
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Kunal
        [1] => 12000
        [2] => 15
        [3] => M
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Kunal
        [1] => 16000
        [2] => 17
        [3] => m
    )
)
that is saved in this variable $detailArray
```

My exporting function is look like this:-

```
Excel::create("Test", function($excel) use($detailArray) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet', function($sheet) use($detailArray) {
            $sheet->fromArray($detailArray, null, 'A1', true);
        });
    })->export('xls');
```

Now when i export excel its look like this:-
[image]

Now i want to remove the 0,1,2,3 these keys as showing in image.
Please help me how to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have done this. Hope in future it will help others. Need to pass false in FromArray Function.

Change this

```
$sheet->fromArray($data);
```

to

```
$sheet->fromArray($detailArray, null, 'A1', false, false);
```

Comment: I've been searching forever for this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the config file `excel` and under `export` array, change the `generate_heading_by_indices` to `false`. That should remove the heading indexes used because that signifies either to use the attributes names or the indices of the array as heading.

[image]

> NB: This is for `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"`

Since you want to remove `array keys for tis function not for all exporting functions` then you can do

```
config(['excel.export.generate_heading_by_indices' => false]);
//my other export functions below
```

> NB: I have not tested this.

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to remove the array keys for tis function not for all exporting functions.

Comment: its still coming when i make it false

Comment: You may need to restart your webserver or `php artisan config:clear` since you just changed the configuration

Comment: i am also using this version maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"

Comment: Did you restart your webserver?

Comment: i have found the solution see my answer. thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to do something like this with your query output so it can not take any kind of key while export

```
$tableData = TableListMember::select(DB::RAW('IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m","Team Member","Candidate") as UserType,tbl_tablelist.tablelist_name as TableName, tbl_event.event_code as Weekend, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.first_name, tbl_candidates.first_name) as FirstName, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.last_name, tbl_candidates.last_name) as LastName, tbl_user_roll.st_roll_name as Role, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.address, tbl_candidates.address) as Address, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", tbl_state_county.county, tbl_state_county.county) as County, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.phone_no, tbl_candidates.phone_no) as Phone, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.email, tbl_candidates.email) as Email, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.church, tbl_candidates.church) as Church, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", users.music, "") as Music, IF(tbl_tablelist_members.member_type = "m", IF(users.reunion_group = 0 ,"No","Yes"), "") as Reunion_Group'))
        ->leftjoin('tbl_tablelist','tbl_tablelist.tablelist_id','tbl_tablelist_members.tablelist_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_event','tbl_event.id','tbl_tablelist.event_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_user_roll','tbl_user_roll.id','tbl_tablelist_members.role')
        ->leftjoin('users','users.id','tbl_tablelist_members.member_candidate_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_candidates','tbl_candidates.id','tbl_tablelist_members.member_candidate_id')
        ->leftjoin('tbl_state_county','tbl_state_county.id','tbl_candidates.county_id')

        ->where(DB::RAW('event_id'), $request->id)->orderBy('tbl_tablelist.tablelist_id','ASC')->orderBy('tbl_tablelist_members.displayorder')->get()->toArray();
        // dd($tableData[0]);
        return Excel::create('TableList ',function($excel) use ($tableData) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($tableData) {
            $sheet->fromArray($tableData);
            });
        })->download('csv');
```

May i hope that this query and source code helps you to solving your problem
and you can also write query as per your requirement i had written it for my problem solving purpose and yes it's working code so you feel free to implement this code.